# Why is -o a candidate for deletion from the Microsoft compiler and linker?

Tags: c, visual-studio, command-line

I came across the following, and I am wondering what implications it is going to have on my Cygwin/GNU environment. Should I be using something other than `-o` to name the output from a compile?

Has there been some new standard adopted and do other compilers adhere to it?

What would be the motivation for removing `-o`?

DOS PROMPT> type compile.bat

```
cl.exe -D YY_MAIN=1 lex.yy.c libfl.obj -o foobar
```

DOS PROMPT> compile

```
cl.exe -D YY_MAIN=1 lex.yy.c libfl.obj -o foobar
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
lex.yy.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
/out:lex.yy.exe
/out:foobar.exe
lex.yy.obj
libfl.obj
```

**cl: Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release**

---

As the answer below asks, *Are **they** trying to make more of a rift between Windows and UNIX intentionally?* I hope not. I am hoping I am missing some new convention adopted by all the compilers out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily see a nefarious purpose behind that - it's more likely to be some compatibility-related thing (perhaps -o is interfering with some build system or the other used by some big Microsoft customer or the other.)

However, it *is* annoying when a compiler vendor throws away entrenched practices and learned reflexes.

But the (syntactical and philosophical) differences between the Microsoft compilers and the Unix compilers are bigger than a simple command line switch. To that end, you could try to step away from simple batch build scripts and towards Makefiles - or, better yet, an actual cross-platform build system such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) or [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) (please note that they're just examples, I'm not married to any of them :) ).

Comment: I have the -o option burried deeply down inside of a rather complex structure for cross platform builds.  The example was to boil it down to the simplest possible case.

Comment: I see - that sucks then... However, there may be a lght side (or, rather, a slightly less dark side) - "will be removed in a future release" may mean @VS2025, and by then you might not need it anymore...

Comment: Very late, but I imagine `-o` was deprecated when `-O` for optimizations was introduced, probably at a time when the compiler options were case-insensitive. They are case-sensitive now, so this would require digging way back into the compiler history, possibly back into the DOS days...

Comment: so what should we use instead `/o` now?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You should use [/F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1cb223a.aspx) to set compiler output options.

Comment: Technically you hit the answer directly but I am looking for a motivation for it.

Comment: It's probably not evil, just some PM thought it needed to happen.  Only the compiler team will know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Command line arguments on Windows are different than command line arguments on Unix. They usually start with a / instead of a -, and the arguments to `cl.exe` won't necessarily match those of `cc` on Unix.

Looks like the option you're looking for is [`/Fe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: But why make more differences?

Comment: Windows is a different operating system from Unix. Windows grew from DOS, which had roots in CP/M, which was inspired by the DEC family of command line environments, which used / to prefix switches on the command line. That's also where CRLF for line endings came from.

Comment: Very old, but: `cl` (and all the Microsoft developer tools) accept `-` for option flags as well.